# Resolving "InvalidArgumentError: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'CudnnRNNV2'" for LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build an LSTM Neural Network for Reinforcement Learning and price prediction, however, I keep getting the error as seen below.

I updated tensorflow to 2.4 and installed tensorflow-gpu, and am using using an Nvidia GPU - CUDA and the Cudnn toolkit is installed. The only thought is perhaps it's not targeting or gaining access to my GPU? As in the Error below - it says Registered devices (CPU) - obviously, not including the GPU.

I also tried adding

```
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] =1
```

In order to have tensorflow run off my CPU, but also had no luck with that either, as I get the same error.

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 7.8.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

runfile('C:/Users/james/Data Science/LSTM/LSTM 1.py', wdir='C:/Users/james/Data Science/LSTM')
Train on 227 samples, validate on 26 samples
Epoch 1/50
 64/227 [=======>......................] - ETA: 4sTraceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-95a3ed21b0c0>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/james/Data Science/LSTM/LSTM 1.py', wdir='C:/Users/james/Data Science/LSTM')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/james/Data Science/LSTM/LSTM 1.py", line 140, in <module>
    validation_split=0.1

  File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 819, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)

  File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 342, in fit
    total_epochs=epochs)

  File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 128, in run_one_epoch
    batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)

  File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py", line 98, in execution_function
    distributed_function(input_fn))

  File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py", line 568, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py", line 632, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 2363, in __call__
    return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access

  File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1611, in _filtered_call
    self.captured_inputs)

  File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1692, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))

  File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 545, in call
    ctx=ctx)

  File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\execute.py", line 67, in quick_execute
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)

  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from

InvalidArgumentError: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'CudnnRNNV2' used by {{node sequential/bidirectional/forward_cu_dnnlstm/CudnnRNNV2}}with these attrs: [seed=0, dropout=0, T=DT_FLOAT, input_mode="linear_input", direction="unidirectional", rnn_mode="lstm", is_training=true, seed2=0]
Registered devices: [CPU]
Registered kernels:
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_HALF]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]

     [[sequential/bidirectional/forward_cu_dnnlstm/CudnnRNNV2]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_5441]
```

The code is as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Jan 11 19:41:02 2021

@author: james
"""

import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from pylab import rcParams
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Bidirectional, Dropout, Activation, Dense, LSTM
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import CuDNNLSTM
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential




sns.set(style='whitegrid', palette='muted', font_scale=1.5)

rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 14, 8

RANDOM_SEED = 42

np.random.seed(RANDOM_SEED)


#import data

csv_path = r"C:\Users\james\Data Science\LSTM\ICX-USD.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(csv_path, parse_dates=['Date'])

df = df.sort_values('Date')

df.head()

df.shape

ax = df.plot(x='Date', y='Close');
ax.set_xlabel("Date")
ax.set_ylabel("Close Price (USD)")

# Normalization

scaler = MinMaxScaler()

close_price = df.Close.values.reshape(-1, 1)

scaled_close = scaler.fit_transform(close_price)

scaled_close.shape

np.isnan(scaled_close).any()

scaled_close = scaled_close[~np.isnan(scaled_close)]


scaled_close = scaled_close.reshape(-1, 1)

np.isnan(scaled_close).any()



#Preprocessing

SEQ_LEN = 100

def to_sequences(data, seq_len):
    d = []

    for index in range(len(data) - seq_len):
        d.append(data[index: index + seq_len])

    return np.array(d)

def preprocess(data_raw, seq_len, train_split):

    data = to_sequences(data_raw, seq_len)

    num_train = int(train_split * data.shape[0])

    X_train = data[:num_train, :-1, :]
    y_train = data[:num_train, -1, :]

    X_test = data[num_train:, :-1, :]
    y_test = data[num_train:, -1, :]

    return X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test


X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = preprocess(scaled_close, SEQ_LEN, train_split = 0.95)

X_train.shape

X_test.shape

#Model

DROPOUT = 0.2
WINDOW_SIZE = SEQ_LEN - 1

model = keras.Sequential()

model.add(Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM(WINDOW_SIZE, return_sequences=True),
                        input_shape=(WINDOW_SIZE, X_train.shape[-1])))
model.add(Dropout(rate=DROPOUT))

model.add(Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM((WINDOW_SIZE * 2), return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Dropout(rate=DROPOUT))

model.add(Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM(WINDOW_SIZE, return_sequences=False)))

model.add(Dense(units=1))

model.add(Activation('linear'))


#Training

model.compile(
    loss='mean_squared_error', 
    optimizer='adam'
)

BATCH_SIZE = 64

history = model.fit(
    X_train, 
    y_train, 
    epochs=50, 
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, 
    shuffle=False,
    validation_split=0.1
)


model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)

plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

#Prediction
y_hat = model.predict(X_test)

y_test_inverse = scaler.inverse_transform(y_test)
y_hat_inverse = scaler.inverse_transform(y_hat)
 
plt.plot(y_test_inverse, label="Actual Price", color='green')
plt.plot(y_hat_inverse, label="Predicted Price", color='red')
 
plt.title('Bitcoin price prediction')
plt.xlabel('Time [days]')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show();
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU') ` return `[ ]`? If that is the case, then it definitely means the `GPU` is not configured correctly. For releases 1.15 and older CPU and GPU packages are separate. Where as for current stable release for CPU and GPU you can install it using `$ pip install tensorflow`. Try to install `Tensorflow 2.4` compatible with `CUDA- 11.0` and `cuDNN - 8.0` will resolve your problem. Thanks!